# How to switch from main window to popup window?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, modal-dialog

I'm not talking about the popups like alert, confirm or prompt dialogs.  In the application if I click on a button popup gets opened. I am not able to switch the WebDriver to the popup window.

> I've tried to use getWindowHandles() but it only returns the main window handle.
>
> I also tried switchTo.window("windowname") but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this GWT or Jquery based window?

Comment: It is javascript. javascript:LSellAccomDropDown();Reset('STC', false);

Comment: if it is JavaScript based dialog window, you many no need to move to Modal Window. Most of the time those kind of windows also in same source code level.

`Check following steps:
press button,
wait 2-3 seconds,
set values or do operation in window(without moving to window)`

Comment: @Chandana That isn't working. Driver can't able to identify the elements. It seems Webdriver focus is still on parent window, may be we've to switch the driver to modal window before identifying elements in it.

Comment: Without looking at page level information it's very difficult to help on this kind of issues. :(

Comment: @Chandana I would've already posted the link to the webpage in the question if the webpage was intended for the public.

Comment: Please check the following link for solution. Hope it helps !  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936167/how-to-deal-with-modaldialog-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if we can reproduce your problem. Can you share a picture of your modal dialog and the html that creates the window? Is it the modal dialog seen at http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/showModalDialog2.htm?

Comment: Yeah, it is similar to the one you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Does printing driver.getWindowHandles() show more than one window handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//handle of the master window before clicking the link
String master = driver.getWindowHandle();

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click me")).click();

//logic for waiting for the popup, checking the size to become greater than 1 or breaking after sometime to avoid the infinite loop.
int timeCount = 1;

do
{
   driver.getWindowHandles();
   Thread.sleep(200);
   timeCount++;
   if ( timeCount > 50 ) 
   {
       break;
   }
}
while ( driver.getWindowHandles().size == 1 );

//Assigning the handles to a set
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
//Switching to the popup window.
for ( String handle : handles )
{
    if(!handle.equals(master))
    {
         driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Usually Modular Windows are part of the same DOM, unlike javascripts alerts. Only thing that sets them apart from rest of the page is that they are in different **frame**.

Try to see if this Modular Window lies inside a frame or iframe tag. If any of the parent is frame or iframe then you will have to change the context to that frame before you can performa any action on the Modal Window.

So find the frame do a `driver.switchTo().frame()` and then perform the action on the element you want to. Once the action is done, which would most probably bring you back to the main page. Use `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()` to bring focus back to main page.

**[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879206/how-to-switch-between-frames-in-java-using-webdriver)** SO question will be helpful.

If this does not work it would be helpful to have a look at the page or its HTML.

Comment: This pop does have iframe tag and html, head, body tags and a title tag too. This is what makes me think that it is a different window.

Comment: I thought so. Having a iframe tag (and html, head, body tags under it) makes it kindda of a sub-page within main page. Try my switchTo().frame() method and i am sure it will work. I am going to update a reference link for you in the answer.

Comment: See the order of  tags in the hierarchy is. html, head(title under head), body(iframe under body) then html, head, body under this iframe tag.

Comment: Thats right .. thats how a frame is defined. Try the link I have updated in the answer.... it will work .. :)

Comment: WebDriver is throwing NoSuchFrameException.

Comment: There might be frame within frame (ie frame tag inside another frame tag). Start from top frame and go down till the frame just above the Modal Window. Or if you could point me to the website / html I might be able to do it for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22517/discussion-between-prashant-shukla-and-code-enthusiastic)

Comment: I've seen the whole html source of the main window and there was only one frame "frame". I've also seen the html source of the modal window and it has only one frame "iframe". I am not able to find the html source of modal window in the html source of main window makes me think these two are completely different windows?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using pageobjects?

If you are using this, you will need to find the elements after the popup appears, because initElements will not initialize them if they are not visible when you first open the page.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your talking about a javascript alert.**

```
final Alert a = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
a.accept();
```

or

[Execute JavaScript directly to handle the altert](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?)

and

[Maybe wait for the alert to show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751433/selenium-2-webdriver-check-that-text-exists-before-calling-alert-gettext)

Answer (score 0):

As per webdriver this issue is fixed in 2.16 but still it does not work 
[Support for window.ShowmodalDialog](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=284#c52)

You can use **Java Robot class** for handling such cases.

**Example :**

```
Wait(5000); // Wait for model pop, 
    int keyInput[] =
    {
      KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_E, KeyEvent.VK_L, KeyEvent.VK_E,
      KeyEvent.VK_N, KeyEvent.VK_I, KeyEvent.VK_U, KeyEvent.VK_M,
    };   

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);


    for (int i = 0; i < keyInput.length; i++)
    {    
      robot.keyPress(keyInput[i]);
      robot.delay(100);    
    }  

    robot.delay(1000); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);

    robot.delay(1000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Save Btn
```

The delay between events is necessary otherwise you will miss the events.

Comment: I've been using Robot Class as workaround for the problem. It seems we've to wait for the fix. :(